# How can I rename the template directory/folder - Joomla 1.5

Tags: templates, joomla, directory

I want to rename NOT inner folder(rhuk_milkyway оr others). But exactly folder "templates".

I think it one of the ways to protect site from regular virus attaks.

I changed:

1). folder name
 2). paths in file index.php in that folder

What else must I do?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that renaming templates folder would do any good. You can still see path of template css, js and images in html source.

Lets say you rename your `templates` folder to `secret_folder`, but when viewing html source you will see `/secret_folder/rhuk_milkyway/css/style.css` instead of `/templates/rhuk_milkyway/css/style.css`.

If you're afraid of regular virus attacks - get right folder permissions, and it should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. But this question one of steps to protect joomla site. Other steps: 

remove   <meta name="generator" content="Joomla! 1.5 - Open Source Content Management" /> from head, change rights on folders and others. My objective is to hide that site made on joomla. 
 
 

And we have different attacks.  Some of them simple and stupid. And changing folder's name can stop them.

Comment: Yeah i follow you, but i'm afraid you cannot rename templates folder without hacking joomla core. You can check here for more info: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=363569